# Apache Ant: Unable to call Composer's vendor/bin scripts

Tags: ant, composer-php

I am using Apache Ant for my builds. I have some composer scripts belonging to several vendors in vendor/bin folder. I have added this folder to the system path and if I run the commands on my command window in works but in the build file i get an error.
Is there anything I should be doing differently? Before is an example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project name="MyProject" default="build" basedir=".">
 <target name="phpcpd" description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD">
    <exec executable="phpcpd">
        <arg value="--version" />
    </exec>
</target>
</project>'
```

I get this when I run `ant phpcpd`

```
phpcpd:

BUILD FAILED
C:\xxxxxx\xxxxxxx\build.xml:96: Execute failed: java.io.IO Exce
ption: Cannot run program "phpcpd": CreateProcess error=2, The system  
cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Jav
a13CommandLauncher.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
 java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces

    ...
```

But `phpcpd --version` works on command prompt

Answer (score 0):

ANT is not aware where **phpcpd** is as it doesn't share path with your Command Promt.

One way around it is to create a .bat file to run **phpcpd**

- Create a phpcpd.bat with the following:

  ```
  @echo off
  phpcpd --version
  ```
- Your build scripts to be updated from :

  ```
  <exec executable="phpcpd">
      <arg value="--version" />
  </exec>
  ```

  To: `<exec executable="phpcpd.bat"/>`

*Above assumed with Windows Command Promt*

Comment: The build.xml is going to be in a repository and I want to it to cater for unix and windows users alike. Command prompt can automatically run phpcpd without the .bat extension.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the .phar files of the scripts. That way, the build file became platform independent to a large extent. So

```
<target name="phpcpd" description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD">
    <exec executable="phpcpd">
        <arg value="--version" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Became:

```
<target name="phpcpd" description="Find duplicate code using PHPCPD">
    <exec executable="php">
        <arg value="${phpcpd}" />
        <arg value="--version" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

Where `${phpcpd}` is the path to the phar file

Answer (score 0):

I'm using absolute paths and a configurable executable.properties like this:

*build.xml*

```
<project name="build">
  <property file="executable.properties" />
  <target name="run-phpcd" unless="${phpcpd.skip}">
    <exec executable="${phpcpd.executable}"><!-- .. --></exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

*executable.dist.properties*

```
phpcpd.skip = no
#phpcpd.executable = C:\path\to\phpcpd.bat
phpcpd.executable = /path/to/phpcpd.sh
```

Both files can be committed to your VCS, for usage copy the template file (*.dist.properties) and rename it to executable.properties. Add this file to the ignore list of your VCS.